# How to prevent Right Click option using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to prevent RIGHT CLICK option for IMAGES which we use in web page.

Comment: I am normally annoyed by people questioning my motives instead of just answering the damn question, but do you really want to be hijacking a user's right mouse click? If they want to get your images they will get it one way or the other... Firebug or just looking at the source would be enough to get direct link to any of your images.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent someone from downloading your images? In that case you can pretty much forget about it, because in order to seem the image in a browser is has to be copied to the client and will in most cases be stored somewhere on your disk. Also most browsers include a config option to prevent manipulation of context menues: [Example for Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/media/uploads/gallery/images/668a9022f052f20f795759846994bc3f-1260050698-426-2.png).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning WHY you are attempting to disable right click. If you think you are protecting your images, think again - you are only deterring the computer illiterates (which does have its merit).

Comment: As others have already pointed out here, sure it is.

However, why? All someone has to do is disable Javascript, or view your page source to find the location, or use any number of more complex methods to get the image.

Comment: ...or the highly unorthodox and very complex "Print Screen" :)

Comment: Also, on mac, you can just drag the image off the page wherever you like. You might want to look at having the image not inside an <img> tag and put it inside a <div> as a css background to add further difficulty for the average user.

Comment: If protecting image is the reason a real solution would be to use watermark. Is it another X Y problem?

Comment: I wish people would get off their high horses here, there are innumerable reasons for wanting to do this other than just stopping people downloading the image. If the OP wants to do it, then in the spirit of Q&A then if you know how answer the question. If the OP had said "so users can't download the image" after answering go on to tell them why it's not a complete solution.

Comment: Most people do not even know how to bypass this block.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("contextmenu",function(){
       return false;
    }); 
});
```

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vak9exyk/

Comment: here's how i've extended it to add further difficulty for mac users http://jsfiddle.net/codedog/uKmDX/

Comment: I honestly don't like the idea of preventing right-clicks on an image.

Comment: neither. we are now enablers of a worse interweb

Comment: i just didn't know you could bind contextmenu :)

Comment: Bad interweb design aside, this is one cool lesson for today. Didn't know you could do that. +1 :D

Comment: Works perfect thanks. I am using this on a full screen browser in kiosk mode which I feel is a legit reason to disable to context menu.

Comment: @willdanceforfun - Your fiddle is broken. Also dont use a white image on a white background :P [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKmDX/17/). And OP: `.bind()` is depricated, use `.on()` instead

Comment: Downvoted for promoting web Browser Hijacking and standards breaking actions.

Comment: Could you explain a bit @MartinSpamer ?

Comment: @MartinSpamer Someone explained why they might need it. "I am using this on a full screen browser in kiosk mode which I feel is a legit reason to disable to context menu"... It's not promoting it either, it's answering a question. (Although I agree that disabling a right click is not advised)

Comment: Works fine. Thanks for this tip

Answer (score 17):

I think this should help. Trick is to bind the contextmenu event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this)` was what I was looking for, thanks! Also `.bind()` is depricated, use `.on()` instead

Comment: Thank you.$(this) solved my case as well. Great answer!

Answer (score 8):

`<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" >`

Set these attributes in your selected tag

**See here Working Example -** **https://codepen.io/Developer_Amit/pen/drYMMv**

**No Need JQuery** (like)

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document)[0].oncontextmenu = function() { return false; }

    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        if( e.button == 2 ) {
            alert('Sorry, this functionality is disabled!');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to disable it only on image click the instead of `$(document).mousedown` use `$("#yourimage").mousedown`

Comment: Thanks anu,like i said above... this prevent right click for whole page,i need only for image...

Answer (score 4):

The following code will disable mouse right click from full page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("body").on("contextmenu",function(e){
     return false;
   });
});
```

The full tutorial and working demo can be found from here - [Disable mouse right click using jQuery](http://www.codexworld.com/disable-mouse-right-click-cut-copy-paste-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i have found some useful link, **with live working example.**

I have tried its working fine.

[How to prevent Right Click option using jquery](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/RightClickDisable-JQuery.aspx?id=45)

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Right Click is Disabled");
    });
```

Comment: For me, onmousedown event wasn't firing when hovering over an image on IE - I found that the only way to get an alert to appear was through this event.

Comment: Thank you. you can find some slimier article in the following link. http://www.thedevelopertips.com

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){

            return false;

            });

    });

</script>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, the red links can't be right clicked anymore.

```js
$("ul.someLinks1 a").each(function(i, obj) {

  $(obj).on("contextmenu",function(){
     return false;
  }); 
  
  $(obj).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="someLinks1">
  <li><a href="www.google.de">google</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.de">stackoverflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.test.de">test</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="someLinks2">
  <li><a href="www.foobar.de">foobar</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.foo.de">foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.bar.de">bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
  return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Right click is disabled on this page.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $("img").on('contextmenu', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
        });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [.contextmenu()](https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/) shortcut method. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").contextmenu(function(e){
       return false;
    }); 
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#logo {
    background: url(http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico) no-repeat; 
    width: 182px; 
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Try right-click on the logo.
<div id="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This!!

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
           $("img").on("contextmenu",function(){
       return false;
    }); 
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if( e.button == 2 ) {
         e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're looking into trying to disable the downloading/saving of your images, scripts won't stop that. You would probably have better luck doing this on a server configuration level (like modifying your `.htaccess` for example on Apache).

Try asking this on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).