# how to disable right click menu in html page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a simple way to hide/disable the right click context menu for the whole html page but not in some editable html elements just like input[text] and textarea using jquery.

I know this jquery code, but the below code will disable context menu in all html elements even in editable objects...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you could check for tags that you need like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){
        if(e.target.nodeName != "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA")
             e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Give your id or class name to specify for which area you want to disable, for example:

```
$("#your_id").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to disable for particular tag(replace img)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img").bind("contextmenu",function(){
   return false;
});});
```

Courtesy to Peeter [How to prevent Right Click option using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618109/how-to-prevent-right-click-option-using-jquery)

Comment: At least attribute your source. Edit your answer to include this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618109/how-to-prevent-right-click-option-using-jquery and say that the answer was provided by Peeter.

Comment: I missed it...done it now

Answer (score 1):

For binding it with all element you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();//or return false;
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   <input type="text" id="test1"/>
<input type="text" id="test2"/>
```

JS Code:

```
$( "#test1" ).on( "copy cut paste drop", function() {
            return false;
    });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2u9Y/)

Comment: Have you read my question carefully ?!

Comment: @MJ.Ahmadi Sorry to misread your question,However if by disabling the right click you want to prevent your users from copy,cut,paste or drop something into your textbox i think inspite of disabling the right click you should use the jquery events that calls on cut copy and other events as  a user can also use shortcut keys to cut copy and paste into textbox. I have updated my answer for that also.