# How to disable right click mouse options on Hyper text in an email when we open it in outlook

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, email, outlook

Just want  disable right click mouse options on
Hyper text in an generated email body when we open it in outlook using java script/Jquery.
Some how the below snippet is working when we open the email in the browser but the same is not working when we open in the PC's outlook. Please help on this.
[How to prevent Right Click option using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618109/how-to-prevent-right-click-option-using-jquery)

Please correct me incase the query is invalid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Email clients restrict any JavaScript code in the message bodies for security reasons. So, Outlook ignores any scripts in the message body as well.